# JavaScript/TypeScript: Concatenate string variables and string arrays with accordingly set spaces

Tags: javascript, string, typescript

#### Situation

I want to concatenate string variables and string arrays in TypeScript like in this simple example:

```
// var1, var2: string
// arr1: string[]
const myString = 'result:' + var1 + ' ' + arr1.join(' ') + ' ' var2;
```

I don't want multiple spaces concatenated together and there shouldn't be any spaces at the end.

#### Problem

It is possible that those variables are set to `''` or that the array is empty. These leads to multiple spaces concatenated together which I want to avoid.

#### Question

Is there a more elegant way to concatenate only the set variables separated with exactly one space?

#### Conditions

- The solution should work with more variables/arrays
- The solution should be a one-liner

Comment: `const myString = 'result:' + [var1, ...arr1, var2].filter(s => s?.length ?? 0 > 0).join(' ');`

Comment: @AluanHaddad Your solution looks really interesting but I don't understand it completely. Could you please write it as an answer and explain why you use `s?` and `??` and how they work? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's called [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#:~:text=%20%20%20%20Desktop%20%20%20,74%20%20%20IE%20No%20support%20No%20). My comment is almost exactly the same as @SpoonMeiser's answer, which I hadn't noticed. `s?.length` evaluates to `undefined if `s` is `undefined` or `null`, where `s.length` would throw. `??` a fallback

Comment: @AluanHaddad and that `0 > 0` part?

Comment: So, if `s` is `null` or `undefined` then `s?.length` will evaluate to `undefined` And `undefined > 0` evaluates to `false` (as does `undefined < 0`) so `s?.length ?? 0` specifies that `0` should be used as a fallback. The thought here is to treat `null` or `undefined` values as if they were empty strings, filtering them out.

Comment: Technically,  the `?? 0` is unnecessary in this specific case, since `undefined > 0 === false`, but you tagged this with [typescript] which will complain if you perform comparisons with operands of type `number | undefined`. I think TS is right to do so as this is a bug waiting to happen in so many cases.

Comment: @AluanHaddad ah, thank you! I think now I get it! So if `0` is used as a fallback, `0 > 0` evaluates to `false`. The same holds for the case where the string is empty and has a length of `0`. Only in the case where `s` is set, the length is bigger than `0` and the expression evaluates to `true` to filter that element. But isn't that a much more complex version of `(s => s)`? Or are there any advantages?

Comment: That's an excellent point. It is more definitely more complex. It could be useful if you wanted to do something like `s => s?.Trim()?.length ?? 0 > 0` to remove whitespace only strings, but that isn't what you asked for. Honestly, I don't recall why I used it here but you are correct that it could be replaced with `s => s` or `Boolean`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use destructuring to concatenate everything into a temporary array, and then use filter to remove any empty elements before calling join on the lot.

```js
let var1 = "var1";
let arr1 = ["one", "", "two"];
let var2 = ""

const myString = "result:" + [var1, ...arr1, var2].filter(s => s).join(' ');

console.log(myString);
```

Comment: you can also move `"result:"` inside the array

Comment: instead of `(s => s)` you could write `.filter(Boolean)`

Comment: will this trim additional spaces from the word, for example let var1 = "xyz     "?
if not, then ll have to trim every element

Comment: @Ifaruki how is `.filter(Boolean)` an improvement over the identity function? Are there any advantages?

Comment: @Ifaruki `.filter(s => s)` seems for me to be more readable than `.filter(Boolean)` because on a first glance I wouldn't know what `Boolean` implicitly does? I would guess that it would be similar to `.filter(true)` but that wouldn't work, right?

Comment: @winklerrr its the equivalent to `.filter(el => Boolean(el))` it converts the value to an boolean and returns true or false. Its one of the few functions that you can write like this in the callback

Comment: I think `.filter(Boolean)` probably communicates the intent a little clearer

Answer (score 1):

Does this satisfy your requirements?

```js
const strArr = ['result:' + var1, ...arr1, var2].map((a) => a.trim()).join(' ')
```

**Update**

As suggested, following handles

1. empty string
2. string with multiple spaces
3. trim additional spaces

```js
const strArr = ['result:' + var1, ...arr1, var2].map((a) => a.trim()).filter(Boolean).join(' ')
```

**Update 2**

If you are using ES2019, you could do this in single pass:

```js
const strArr = 
['result:' + var1, ...arr1, var2]
         .flatMap((el) => Boolean(el.trim()) ? [el.trim()] :[]).join(' ')
```

Comment: I really like about your solution that you thought about the edge case where the variables could also include spaces! When you now integrate the filter function in your answer, it would completely fulfil my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:
`const cleanedResult = result.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ').trim()`

This would remove multiple spaces in your variables as well though.

If you do not want that you can try out this solution:

```
const result = 'result:' + (var1 ? var1 + ' ' : '')  + (arr1 ? arr1.join(' ') : '') + (var2 ? var2 + ' ' : '')
```

Comment: The usage of the ternary operator for every variable seems to be an overkill. Especially if I need to work with more variables.